# Are there extensions of the latent-class growth model where also the outcome is unobserved?

Tags: latent-variable, mediation, growth-model, latent-class

In my understanding, in a repeated-measure setting, Latent-Class Growth Models (LCGM's) use latent factor to represent growth parameters. In my case, I have repeated measures where **also the outcomes (and the mediators) are not observed** (but estimated by a set of items). In particular, I want to estimate the effect of an intervention on an outcome in a model including 4 mediators. I have observations at baseline (where, of course, the intervention cannot have any impact) and at two follow-up points. I've seen that, if my outcome and mediators were observed, I could perform a latent-class growth model. However, both the outcome and mediators are unobserved, and I have a set of items to estimate them. If I used such estimates to inform my LCGM, how could I take the fact that my variables are estimated (and not measured) into account? Otherwise, how could I estimate everything simultaneously? A further complication wrt the two-step approach is that an Item-Response Theory model should be adopted in that case, since my data come from different groups, on which different (overlapping but not identical) sets of items are measured.

**EDITED ON MAY 8 2018**

Such graph (**circles stand for latent factors, rectangles for observed variables**):

[image]
describes my situations, with some caveats:

1) I have this for time to follow-up 1 and 2: I have also data at baseline but, since the treatment has not been implemented then, no effect of the treatment is possible (and its associations with mediators and outcome may only be due to chance).

2) The items for each latent factor are many more than $3$ (they are dozens).

3) I am in a multi-group situation, where each group has a different (partly overlapping with the other groups) set of items. There are some pairs of items that are not simultaneously present in any group.

Comment: It sounds like you could specify a new latent variable to be the outcome, and this variable will be measured in the usual way, with error. Same for the mediators (possibly). Without some more details of your data and proposed model it is hard to be sure, so please can you post a path diagram and more information...

Comment: Thank you Robert: I added the graph and listed some points below to explain why my situation is more complicated than what implied by it.

Comment: Query:  ¿Are A1, B1, C1, ... the same thing measured at different times?

Comment: No, the graph only refers to cross-section data. I mean: this is the situation for time $0$, that is then replicated for times $1$ and $2$. Thus, $A_1$, $A_2$ and $A_3$ are simultanous, but then are also measured at $2$ follow-up times.